# How to add a decimal to jQuery animated counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animated jquery counter that's working fine, but I want to change the end number to a decimal number. So at the moment it's counting up to 54000, but I want it to give me 54,000. How do I do this?

jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rn3yabv2/)

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  
        $(".animated_stats").each(function () {
            _this = $(this);
                _this.find('.counter').each(function () {
                    var $this = $(this),
                        countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

                    $({ countNum: $this.text() }).animate({
                        countNum: countTo
                    },

                        {

                            duration: 2000,
                            easing: 'linear',
                            step: function () {
                                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                                $this.text(this.countNum);
                            }
                        });

                });
            
        });

    });
```

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animated_stats">
  <h1 class="counter" data-count="54000"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What about manipulating the string parameter for `$(this).text()`?

Comment: Try looking at [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).
Replace `$this.text(this.countNum);` with `$this.text(this.countNum.toLocaleString());`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".animated_stats").each(function () {
          _this = $(this);
          _this.find('.counter').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
            $({ countNum: $this.text() }).animate({
              countNum: countTo
            }, {
              duration: 2000,
              easing: 'linear',
              step: function () {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum).toLocaleString());
              },
              complete: function () {
                $this.text(this.countNum.toLocaleString());
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
```

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animated_stats">
  <h1 class="counter" data-count="54000"></h1>
</div>
```